# Show that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are not Linearly Independent

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are solutions of the differential equation $y''+py'+qy=0$ on $I$. How can I show that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ vanish at the same point then they are not linearly independent?

Here is my attempt to prove the problem. Since $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are solutions of the differential equation $y''+py'+qy=0$ on $I$, it is enough for me to show that the Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$ denoted by $W(y_1,y_2)$ is zero. Now since $y_1$ and $y_2$ vanish at the same point say $p$ we have $y_1(p)=0$ and also $y_2(p)=0$.

Solving for $W(y_1,y_2)(p)$ we have: $y_1(p)y_2'(p)-y_2(p)y_1'(p)=0$ since $y_1(p)=0$ and also $y_2(p)=0$.

Am I correct?
Thanks

Comment: I think you can use the Wronskian, although I don't think it's foolproof for showing linear dependence.

Comment: Thanks @Mattos will try your suggestion, and post my attempt to the question whenever I'm done. Hope I will.

Comment: @Mattos I agree with you,``I don't think it's foolproof for showing linear dependence." Since we only have If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are Linearly Dependent then the Wronskian $W(y_1,y_2)=0$ for all $x\in I$.

Comment: But with the assumption that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions of the d.e. above it is enough for me to show that there wRONSKIAN is always zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $y_1$ and $y_2$ vanish at $t_0$. Then both functions satisfy the initial value problem $y''+py'+qy=0$ with $y(t_0)=0$.

If we complement the initial-value problem with an initial value of the type $y'(t_0)=c$, $c\in\mathbb R$, then the equation is uniquely solvable.

Moreover, we observe that the mapping $S:c\mapsto y$ is linear, where $S$ is the solution mapping of the differential equation, mapping the initial value $y'(t_0)=c$ to the whole trajectory.

Now, $y_1'(t_0)$ and $y_2'(t_0)$ are values in the one-dimensional vector space $\mathbb R$, thus they are linearly dependent. Hence their images under $S$ - the trajectories $y_1$ and $y_2$ - are linearly dependent.

Comment: Thanks daw, I will try to absorb your answer and ask a question whenever I have.

Comment: Great Answer :) Thanks for it!