# About zeroes of solutions of second order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving the following problem:

$y_1$ and $y_2$ are the solutions of

$x^2y'' + y'+ (sin x)y = 0$ which satisfy $y_1(0)=0,y_1'(0)=1$ and $y_2(0)=1,y_2(0)='0$.

For the above problem my solution is :

Using Abel's formula we get wronskian as  ***$ce^\frac{1}{x}$*** $\neq 0$ except at $x=0$. This implies that given two solutions are L.I.

Can we say that since these these two solutions are LI, they don't have a common zero.

Somewhere I read this result but I am not sure about this. Kindly clarify my doubt. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Related:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136259/show-that-y-1-and-y-2-are-not-linearly-independent

Comment: $W(x)\neq0$ implies solutions are LI.

Answer (score 0):

But the fact that they are "linearly independent" does NOT mean that they do not have a "common zero".  The functions $y_1= x^2- 1$ and $y_2= 1- x^2$ are linearly independent but have the common zeros x= 1 and x= -1.